# Rails user authentication: can you hardcode a user?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, dbmigrate, hardcode

I have a working rails application with user authentication. I want to automatically have my account coded because I will have the admin role and no one else will. Is there a way to do this?

By the way, my db/migrate table looks like this:

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def change
        create_table :users do |t|
            t.string :first_name
            t.string :last_name
            t.string :email
            t.string :password_digest
            t.string :role, default => 'reader'
            t.timestamps null: false
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: stick your record into the database through the console? You could also make a rake task or a migration

Answer (score 1):

Add a migration (e.g. using `rails generate migration AddAdmin`) that creates a specific user (`User.create(...)`).

Answer (score 0):

I think best way to do this is using `seed` that feature was added in rails 2.3.4

```
db/seeds.rb
```

With in seed file just add your code for ex: `User.create(...)` and run `rake db:seed`

Answer (score 0):

you can write a method like this:

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.create_admin
  create(first_name:"xxx",last_name:"xxx",email:"xxx",password:"xxxx",
    role:"admin")
  end
end
```

Then you run this method in rails console